# Does boost::flyweight do reference counting?

Tags: c++, boost, flyweight-pattern, boost-flyweight

I've been reading the documentation of [`boost::flyweight`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) but i don't see any mention to deallocation or reference counting policies. Basically a flyweight object should behave like a repository of distinct values, but its not clear what happens when a distinct value is not used anymore.

Is it already supported? can it be enabled with some custom factory?

Comment: Did you check the source code?

Comment: yes there seems to be an include with an empty `refcounted` struct being used in some of the template parameters for the tracking policy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with most things in Flyweight, this behavior is dictated by policy, specifically by the [Tracking Policy](http://www.boost.org/libs/flyweight/doc/reference/tracking.html#tracking). The [default tracking policy](http://www.boost.org/libs/flyweight/doc/reference/flyweight.html#instantiation_types) is `refcounted`:

> Tracking Policy providing flyweight instantiations with reference counting semantics: when all the flyweight objects associated to a given value are destroyed, the corresponding entry is erased from flyweight's internal factory.